# Problems with shutting down JBoss in Eclipse if I change JNDI port

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss-tools

## 1st phase

I have a problem shutting down my running JBoss instance under Eclipse since I changed
  the JNDI port of JBoss. Of course I can shut it down from the console view but not with
  the stop button (it still searches JNDI port at the default 1099 port). I'm looking
  forward to any solutions. Thank you!

### Used environment:

- JBoss 4.0.2  (using *default*)
- Eclipse 3.4.0. (using JBoss Tools 2.1.1.GA)

Default ports: 1098, 1099
Changed ports: 11098, 11099

I changed the following part in jbosspath/server/default/conf/jboss-service.xml:

```
   <!-- ==================================================================== -->
   <!-- JNDI                                                                 -->
   <!-- ==================================================================== -->

   <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.NamingService"
      name="jboss:service=Naming"
      xmbean-dd="resource:xmdesc/NamingService-xmbean.xml">
      <!-- The call by value mode. true if all lookups are unmarshalled using
      the caller's TCL, false if in VM lookups return the value by reference.
      -->
      <attribute name="CallByValue">false</attribute>
      <!-- The listening port for the bootstrap JNP service. Set this to -1
        to run the NamingService without the JNP invoker listening port.
      -->
      <attribute name="Port">11099</attribute>
      <!-- The bootstrap JNP server bind address. This also sets the default
      RMI service bind address. Empty == all addresses
       -->
      <attribute name="BindAddress">${jboss.bind.address}</attribute>
      <!-- The port of the RMI naming service, 0 == anonymous -->
      <attribute name="RmiPort">11098</attribute>
      <!-- The RMI service bind address. Empty == all addresses
       -->
      <attribute name="RmiBindAddress">${jboss.bind.address}</attribute>
      <!-- The thread pool service used to control the bootstrap lookups -->
      <depends optional-attribute-name="LookupPool"
         proxy-type="attribute">jboss.system:service=ThreadPool</depends>
   </mbean>

   <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIView"
        name="jboss:service=JNDIView"
        xmbean-dd="resource:xmdesc/JNDIView-xmbean.xml">
   </mbean>
```

### Eclipse setup:

[image]

*About my JBoss Tools preferences:* 
I had a previous version, I got this problem, I read about some bugfix in JbossTools, so updated to 2.1.1.GA. Now the buttons changed, and I've got a new preferences view, but I cannot modify anything...seems to be abnormal as well:

[image]

### Error dialog:

[image]

### The stacktrace:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1385)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:579)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:572)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:347)
    at org.jboss.Shutdown.main(Shutdown.java:202)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:254)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1370)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:228)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:305)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:171)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:158)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:452)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:402)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:309)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:69)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:62)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:224)
    ... 5 more
Exception in thread "main"
```

## 2nd phase:

After creating a new Server in File/new/other/server, it did appear in the preferences tab. Now the stop button is working (the server receives the shutdown messages without any additional modification of the jndi port -- there is no opportunity for it now) but it still throws an error message, though different, it's without exception stack trace: "Server JBoss 4.0 Server failed to stop."

Comment: Have you looked through the JBossTools preferences in Eclipse to see if you can change the port that Eclipse expects JBoss to be listening on?

Comment: Skaffman - you should "post answer" more often instead of commenting so I can vote you up. Your comments are often better then many of the answers.

Comment: Yes you should post this comment as an answer! I think it will lead to the solution...BTW, I updated the question with the jbosstools prefs.
Thanks!

Comment: OK, done.... I often find myself reluctant to post things as answers when I'm not sure if they are actually answering anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, what you have to do is File->New->Other->Server, and set up your JBoss server there. It will then appear in Preferences->JBossTools->Servers.

Convoluted.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a detailed fix for this problem:
The Eclipse WTP server connector won't shut down JBoss when the jndi port is remapped.

This is because the default server connector profiles don't use their own alias for the jndiPort. This problem is also discussed at eclipse.org:
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=489439&S=0db4920aab0a501c80a626edff84c17d#msg_489439

The solution comes from the .serverdef files in eclipse:

```
<eclipse>\plugins\org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.jboss_1.5.105.v200709061325\servers\jboss*.serverdef
```

They declare an xml property for the jndi port:

```
<property id="jndiPort"
 label="%jndiPort"
 type="string"
 context="server"
 default="1099" />
```

This simply needs to be used where the serverdef has the STOP command coded:

So this:

```
 <stop>
  <mainClass>org.jboss.Shutdown</mainClass>
  <workingDirectory>${serverRootDirectory}/bin</workingDirectory>
  <programArguments>-S</programArguments>
  <vmParameters></vmParameters>
  <classpathReference>jboss</classpathReference>
 </stop>
```

becomes this:

```
 <stop>
  <mainClass>org.jboss.Shutdown</mainClass>
  <workingDirectory>${serverRootDirectory}/bin</workingDirectory>
  <programArguments>-s jnp://${serverAddress}:${jndiPort}</programArguments>
  <vmParameters></vmParameters>
  <classpathReference>jboss</classpathReference>
 </stop>
```

The philosophy for this can be verified by comparison to the definition for the jndi connection:

```
 <jndiConnection>
  <providerUrl>jnp://${serverAddress}:${jndiPort}</providerUrl>
<initialContextFactory>org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</initialContextFactory>
  <jndiProperty>
   <name></name>
   <value></value>
  </jndiProperty>
 </jndiConnection>
```

Credit for the inspiration for this general case fix goes to: Moisa Laurentiu Florin. It was their contribution that got me to look for a way of substituting in the ${jndiPort} instead of a hard coded value.

This fix corrects both plain Eclipse WTP server connector. I'm still investigating the JBOss IDE connector

Answer (score 3):

Open jboss-path\bin\shutdown.jar

example: jboss-4.2.3.GA\bin\shutdown.jar

and open jboss-path\bin\shutdown.jar\jndi.properties

and change

java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099 to java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:11099

Answer (score 0):

In MyEclipse server configuration, you find the field "Optional Shutdown Argument", which is filled with the default value

```
--shutdown
```

Change it to

```
-s jnp://localhost:11099 --shutdown
```

Edited:

Sorry, this answer is related to MyEclipse. However, there must be some place where you can specify the JBoss shutdown command in your environment as well.
Maybe you take a look at the "Run..." configurations?

Comment: I cannot find the field (see the "eclipse setup" image, those are the fields I have.

Answer (score 0):

you should modify in the file "/home/fmoisa/workspace/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.jboss_1.5.206.v20090115/servers/jboss42.serverdef" this:

org.jboss.Shutdown
        ${serverRootDirectory}/bin
        -S
        -Djboss.boot.loader.name=shutdown.bat
        jboss.shutdown

to this:

org.jboss.Shutdown
        ${serverRootDirectory}/bin
        -S -sjnp://localhost:11099
        -Djboss.boot.loader.name=shutdown.bat
        jboss.shutdown

gl all ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the server adapter provided by JBoss tools and not the one that comes default from Eclipse WTP.

Then you can simply double click on the server and you can edit the JNDI port (which btw. is automatically picked up from the XML configuration if you don't do any thing). You can also do the trick about setting the JNDI port via command line arguments in the Launch Configuration but that is more trouble than just setting the port values.

Answer (score 0):

This was changed in JBoss 6.0.0M3.

The stop command is now:

> "- s service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1090/jmxrmi"

Note that the port also changed: **It is no longer the JNDI port at 1099**, but **RMI/JMX port 1090**. So, you will need another config parameter in the server definition.

I don't know whether the "JNDI port" parameter is required at all for JBoss 6.0.0M3 servers.

I have a modified eclipse plugin at http://www.cs.hs-rm.de/~knauf/public/ which contains a server definition for 6.0.0M3 including this change. This site also links to a JBoss forum thread with more details about this change.

Best regards

Wolfgang Knauf